# Elasticsearch Completion Suggester: Real tokenization possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, autocomplete

As stated [here](https://medium.com/@mourjo_sen/a-detailed-comparison-between-autocompletion-strategies-in-elasticsearch-66cb9e9c62c4) a field in Elasticsearch, defined as type "completion" together with a certain analyzer + tokenizer, is first split up according to the underlying logic of those parts and then "stitched" together again. However I'm verry unhappy with this behaviour.

This is my current mapping setup (excerpt):

```
"mappings": {
    "movie": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "analyzer": "standard",
          "fields": {
            "autocomplete": {
              "type": "completion"
              "analyzer": "whitespace",
            }
          },
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Let's take a movie with the title `Harry Potter` for example:

When I enter the prefix `Har` I get the suggestion `Harry Potter`. When I enter `Pot` instead, I get no result at all, because the individual tokens `Harry` and `Potter` were stitched together to `Harry Potter` immediately after analyzing/tokenizing.

Now what I would like is the following behaviour: When I enter `Pot` I'd want the Completion Suggester to return `Potter`. Not `Harry Potter`, but simply `Potter`. Is this somehow possible? Caution: I don't even need the reference to the document which created the suggestion. So if it's somehow possible to throw all generated tokens in a pot and then retrieve suggestions from there, that would be awesome (due to some other stuff I have to do).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm looking to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'll tell you tomorrow at work, when I have the code by my side ;)

Comment: @XDAF could you please share the solution?

I have asked the same question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355182/elasticsearch-autocomplete-suggest-by-token

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something very similar using an edge_ngram tokeniser. Here's the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Your settings would need to include something like:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_shards" : "5",
      "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 20,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and your mapping would need to be refined so that "analyser": "autocomplete"

Comment: But then a movie with the title `Harry Potter` is divided in the tokens `Har, Harr, Harry, Pot, Pott, Potte, Potter`. I'd just like to split it in two tokens and then use the logic of the binary search tree of the completion suggester.